# Business Process Modelling 2.0

Tags: model, bpmn

I need help modelling this scenario using BPMN. I can do it using lots of activities and a activity call, but there must be a more efficient way.

Scenario:

- A mechanic inspects component A, component B and component C
- For each component, the mechanic performs the same 3 steps (checking for leaks, checking for signs of wear and tear, checking for physical damage)

So far I've got a diagram with a call activity. The call activity encapsulates the 3 steps. Then it's like this

```
    Inspect component A --> Call Activity
--> Inspect Component B --> Call Activity 
--> Inspect Component C --> Call Activity ... etc
```

Can someone please help see if there is a more elegant way?

Comment: Is the order of components inspection relevant or can it be done in any order? Does the check always contain 3 components (A, B, C) or can it change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a reusable [sub-process](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/):

[image: Corrected BPMN of the question]

Feel free to reuse the [source-code](https://pastebin.com/UDXWhBCe):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="1.8.2">
  <bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
...
```

Comment: Yes, the subprocess is indeed a generic one. A single one for all components. If you need additional parameters to specify the given component, you could probably do so, I have to ask my team how to sctually do parameter-parsing in practice.

Comment: Oh, I just forgot that, it should look exactly as the tasks before. The "yes" goes to "Fix damage", the "No" to "Component checked". Then, there is an arrow from "Fix damage" to "Component checked" missing. I will edit that [rsn](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RSN).